# Bootstrap Grid Unknown Table Sizes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is quite an ambiguous question however...
I have a bootstrap grid layout set to 4 columns wide.  I have an application that automatically generates tables based on information from a text file.  Each one of these tables is added to a column.  Currently there are 9 tables all with different lengths (some are 2.5 times taller than the smallest table).

As such the tables look pretty badly arranged on the screen with big white spaces where a table has been placed on a row below because it didn't fit.

Is there a better way to arrange/size/limit these tables?
e.g. each number represents a table in my grid, where the number is doubled the table extends into the row below.

```
O 1 2 3
O 1 4 5
    4 5
6 7 8
```

The html code is also generated by the application (asp c# behind), the html has the pattern of:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="dashboard">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span3">
        <div class="table responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
            <tr class="info">
              <th colspan="3">TABLENAME</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="info">
              <td>Column1</td>
              <td>Column2</td>
            </tr>
                 ...
             unknown amount of rows
                 ...
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      ...
      unknown amount of tables
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please show the code.

Comment: How are u adding tables to columns? From the HTML shown above its now clear how you are defining columns.

Comment: The <div class="span3"> defines a column to span 3 of the 12 available columns.  A table is added to a div and then this div is added to the span3 column div.